# Is there a way to copy an image on illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, print-design, illustration

Is there a way that I can copy a image that is black and white on Illustrator. I want to highlight the black parts in the image and then copy/import them to a blank file so that I can print it as a sticker and have a clear background? Or would this be easier to do on Photoshop? either way are you able to help me in what program/setting is best suited for this task?

Comment: Welcome to GDSE! Please make sure to read our [help](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) to see how best to use the site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a very elementary question. While this question may inquire about commonly used graphic design tools, this has little to do with actual graphic design.

Answer (score 3):

Choice of tools is always a personal preference although some tools work better for certain tasks than others.

For stickers (or finely-cut materials) a vector-based tool (like Illustrator) will likely be ideal.

You can bring a pixel-based image - like a photo - into Illustrator (and most other vector-based tools). Then use Illustrator's tools to "trace" the shapes you need. Do this manually - don't use the Image Trace tool and functionality unless you like to spend lots of time cleaning up automated results.

Once complete, you can remove or hide the photo you used as a guide.

Also work with your chosen printer - often printers will have certain ways they want files to be created and sent to them. Save yourself time and money by finding out and following these guidelines **before** you send them your artwork!